# How to copy specific rows from 3 google spreadsheet to another spreadsheet using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet named Main-spreadsheet ,within them are 4 spreadsheets named sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 & result. I want to copy conditional data from sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 to result sheet.Can anyone pls help me????

This is my code:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];

  var dataSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var dataSheet = dataSs.getSheets()[0];

  // Fetch all the data
  var data = getRowsData(dataSheet);

  // This is the data we want to display
  var columnNames = ["Name", "AC link", "Type"];

  // Index data by type
  var dataBytype = {};
  var types = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (!dataBytype[rowData.type]) {
      dataBytype[rowData.type] = [];
      types.push(rowData.type);
    }
    dataBytype[rowData.type].push(rowData);
  }

  types.sort();
  var headerBackgroundColor = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1).getBackgroundColor();
  for (var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(types[i]) || 
        ss.insertSheet(types[i], ss.getSheets().length);
    sheet.clear();
    var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, columnNames.length);
    headersRange.setValues([columnNames]);
    headersRange.setBackgroundColor(headerBackgroundColor);
    setRowsData(sheet, dataBytype[types[i]]);
  }
```

}

it currently copy data fom sheet1 and makes a new sheet by type column

Answer (score -1):

There has been dozens of similar questions ***and answers*** on this forum and on [the old one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support)... a quick search will help you to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I have gone through that but my problem is how to select data from multiple sheets(i am able to select data from single sheet and copy to another)

Comment: You can use [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet?hl=fr-FR#getSheetByName) for example...

Comment: Can you please paste the code you have tried along with any error that you may have seen